# Hard to spot memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I came up with a solution to parse contiguous chunked streaming data. The data contains multiple datasets, which are easily identified by a start and stop ASCII sequence. I'm using strcmp and comparable functions to parse the data.

The function that receives the chunked data calls `appendToBuffer(data, data_length);` for each new chunk that has arrived.

The appendToBuffer function also calls the processing function. The processing function will parse the first dataset available in the buffer (recursively) and gives a callback on the amount of bytes that have recursively been parsed. These bytes are then removed from the front of the buffer.

When new chunked data comes in at this stage, the buffer gets expanded, which I've implemented in the safe_realloc function, the data gets copied into the buffer and the parsing process repeats.

I've got a memory leak, that's for sure. I can see the heap go down significantly with every chunked data bit that comes in.
I've enabled the memory analyzer, which obviously points the leak towards the safe_realloc functions malloc, but I think that this is only because the heap tracing only exists around the appendToBuffer function call and expects any allocated memory to be freed whenever the function returns.
However, it's on purpose that the buffer remains intact whenever the appendToBuffer function returns.

Could anybody help me resolve my memory leak issue?
I'm also open to a whole new implementation using C++ standard libraries

```
bool appendToBuffer(uint8_t* data, size_t len){

  // Either create a new buffer, or grow the existing one
  if(length == 0 || buffer == NULL){
    if(buffer != NULL)
      free(buffer);

    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "New buffer");
    buffer = (char*)malloc(len);
  }else{
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Realloc buffer");
    buffer = safe_realloc(buffer, length, length+len);
  }

  ESP_LOGD(TAG,"Free heap: %u", (unsigned int) esp_get_free_heap_size());

  assert(buffer != NULL);

  // Copy the new data into the buffer at the right spot, which is the length that is already in the buffer
  memcpy(buffer + length, data, len);

  // The buffer has just grown in size
  length += len;

  // Process the current buffer and know what to remove from the front of the buffer
  size_t bytesProcessed = processBuffer();

  // Remove these bytes from the front of the buffer
  size_t tempBufferLength = length-bytesProcessed;

  // Remove the first vCard in the buffer, as it has been processed
  if (bytesProcessed > 0 && tempBufferLength > 0){

    char* tempBuffer = (char*)malloc(tempBufferLength);

    // Copy the buffer, except the first vCard to a temp buffer
    memcpy(tempBuffer, buffer+bytesProcessed, tempBufferLength);

    free(buffer);

    // Shrink the buffer
    buffer = (char*)malloc(tempBufferLength);

    assert(buffer != NULL);

    // Copy the tempbuffer back to the buffer
    memcpy(buffer, tempBuffer, tempBufferLength);

    // Clean the tempbuffer
    free(tempBuffer);

    // Set the length
    length=tempBufferLength;
  }

  ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Remaining buffer: (len=%d) %s", length, buffer);

  // If all the data in the buffer has been parsed, free the buffer
  if(length == 0){
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Freeing buffer");
    free(buffer);
  }


  return true;
}

static char* safe_realloc(char* original, size_t original_len, size_t new_len){
  if(original_len == new_len)
    return original;

  if(new_len == 0){
    free(original);
    return NULL;
  }

  char* buffer = (char*)malloc(new_len);
  assert(buffer != NULL);
  assert(original != NULL);

  if (new_len < original_len) {
      // Shrinks, only copy the first new_len bytes
      memcpy(buffer, original, new_len);
  } else {
      // Expands, copy the entire original buffer
      memcpy(buffer, original, original_len);
  }

  free(original);

  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: *Could anybody help me resolve my memory leak issue?* -- Start with `std::vector` and properly call the `insert()`, `push_back()`, etc. functions to manipulate the vector's buffer.

Comment: You're suggesting to use a std::vector for each character in the data stream and to manipulate it that way?

Comment: Yes.  Your code is inefficient if you were to compare it to what `std::vector` does, let alone how much simpler the code would be.  Second, even in your code, it is flawed since it fails to check if `malloc` returns NULL here: `char* tempBuffer = (char*)malloc(tempBufferLength);`

Comment: [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/4axY5ToGj).

Comment: If this is supposed to be a C question, fix the tags. Otherwise, the C++ way is entirely different; Learn to use `std::vector` instead of all the memory management noise.

Comment: (1) Please tag this `C`, not `C++`. There is absolutely nothing C++-related in the entire snippet. Using the right tags shows your question to the right people. (2) _“Could anybody help me resolve my memory leak issue?”_ Yes. Definitely. His name is `valgrind`. He’s a cool dude and you should take his advice. On a `-g`-compiled binary, he will even give you the exact spot in code at which the leaked memory was allocated (and how much of it there was and all sorts of interesting information). `valgrind` FTW!

Comment: Here's a very simple and very important question. Please do answer it. *Are you using C or C++?*

Comment: The question is now tagged both `C` and `C++`. That makes no sense. They are different languages. (And there is still **no** C++ anywhere in the question.)

Comment: Functions should do **one** thing and do it well... Rewrite this code, and its caller, **separating** _appending_ ("growing") from _processing_ ("shrinking"). You'd be done now had you not tried to re-invent `realloc()`... And, you'll be interested in `memmove()` to shift the remaining data to the front of the buffer before shrinking the buffer size. (The mention of _recursion_ gives me the willies!!)

Comment: I've switched to std::strings for my solution, which supports some of the operations that I'd like to do out-of-the box.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to implement a data structure; perhaps if you explained what you intended? Not sure how _removed from the front of the buffer_ is supposed to work. Do you require it to be contiguous? Use [realloc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/realloc.html)?

Comment: "_I've switched to std::strings for my solution" Then WHY is this question tagged 'C'? `std::strings` is **not** valid C syntax!

Comment: That's why I had both tags in there at the first place, I am using C in C++ code, so by that I was letting you know that I'm open to C++ solutions

Comment: If you want to “remove from the front of the buffer”, **you want `std::deque`**, one of the most important (and most overlooked) STL structures. (I have seen way too many cases of `std::vector` abuse or `std::list` performance disaster where a`std::deque` would have saved the day.) And please don’t try to reimplement `std::deque`…

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek `std::deque` seems to suite the issue, but I'm wondering how one would actually use `strstr`, `strcmp` on a `std::deque`.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek We don't tag based on how the code looks, but on what compiler OP uses.

Comment: One would not use `strstr`, `strcmp` or any other `str...` functions in C++ at all. The string data type in C++ is spelled `std::string`.

Comment: @tim687 There is neither a reason nor a possibility to use _any_ C functions on STL containers. `std::deque` has [the regular operator overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_cmp). Also, [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) is what you use for lookups in C++, not something from C.